# Seeking open-source PDE Solver for inhomogeneous material properties

Tags: finite-element, pde, software-recommendation, open-source

I'm currently in search of an open-source PDE solver (Finite Element Method is preferred) that can effectively handle the challenge of material properties coefficients associated with each element in mesh data (inhomogeneous material properties).

To provide more context, I'm working on a versatile method applicable to various analyses involving different types of PDEs. My aim is to obtain initial results with minimal effort to better understand how I can enhance my data. As such, I'm looking for a streamlined solution that can facilitate this initial exploration. Python and Fortran are preferred.

If anyone has recommendations or insights into suitable packages for this specific requirement, I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

Comment: You will have a hard time finding finite-element problems that deal.ii can't handle: https://www.dealii.org/

Comment: Thank you for your input! I explored the tutorial, specifically [step-8](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_8.html), and you're right, it seems quite capable with `std::vector<double> lambda_values(n_q_points);`. However, for my specific problem, I'm leaning towards a more streamlined solution, preferably in Python. I'm looking for a smaller package with a more straightforward approach.

Comment: FEniCS may be a good choice then.

Comment: If you want to get a useful recommendation, edit your question to include more information.  For instance, you added some requirements in your comment; put them in the question.  I suggest you also provide more information about the PDE(s) you want to solve (e.g., are they hyperbolic/parbolic/elliptic).

Comment: If all you want is a Poisson solver for spatially variable equations, step-5 will already do that for you: https://dealii.org/developer/doxygen/deal.II/step_5.html

Comment: There is of course also the issue that "more streamlined solution" oftentimes also means "supports fewer things" :-)

Comment: @whpowell96 I've looked into FEniCS as well, but unfortunately, I couldn't locate any tutorials or examples that closely match my specific problem. If you have any pointers or know of relevant resources, I'd be grateful for the guidance.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Appreciate your suggestion. I deliberately kept some details open-ended to gather a broad range of options from the community. I'm working on a method applicable to various types of analysis involving different PDEs. However, your point is well-taken, and I'll enhance my question with the additional information you suggested. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I'll definitely check out step-5. Thanks for the suggestion! Regarding the preference for a "more streamlined solution," it's precisely for the initial phase of obtaining quick results with minimal effort. Once I have a better understanding, I'm open to transitioning to more sophisticated software for further refinements. Appreciate your insights!

Comment: I believe there is a literal textbook on how to use FEniCS on their website for free, but I agree that more details about your problem will get you better feedback

Comment: @whpowell96 Thanks for the tip! While the idea of a literal textbook hunt sounds thrilling, I'm hoping for some more targeted guidance. Something along the lines of "check out this example/tutorial" or "I recall encountering a similar scenario in ..." would be exceptionally helpful. Your expertise is much appreciated!

Comment: Nobody can give advice on a specific scenario because you have not provided any details of your problem other than it contains spatially varying coefficients.